# Does impala work with nested avro structures?

Tags: impala

Assuming I have the following:

```
"properties" : {
"prop1": "propval",
"prop2": 5
"prop3": {"subprop1":"subpropval1","subprop2":"subpropval2"}
}
"testlist" : [
{"key": "item1", "key2": "value1"},
{"key": "item1", "key2": "value1"}
{"key": "item1", "key2": "value1"}
]
```

Is this loadable into Impala and queryable without having to specify schema? Or does it have to be a "flat" avro schema without lists/nested structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested types in avro will be available in Impala 2.2:
https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-345

Answer (score 0):

Querying nested data with Impala is slated for the 2.0 release [1], which should happen in the second half of 2014.

[1] http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/whats-next-for-impala-after-release-1-1/